# Access bucket using S3cmd with IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I have the following configured in ~/.aws/config file.

`[profile profilename]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::106546725123:role/rolename
credential_source = Ec2InstanceMetadata`

i can successfully access an s3 bucket using aws CLI with the below command

`aws s3 ls s3://<bucket_name> --profile profilename`

I now need to access the bucket using s3cmd. Please help with the command to access the bucket using s3cmd using IAM role.

The version fo s3cmd installed is 1.5.0-alpha2

Comment: Related: https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/570

Comment: Why do you wish to use `s3cmd`? Is there a capability missing from the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) that you require?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes